# Why is the Weibull distribution considered as a model for lifetime of a system where parts are getting worn-out?

Tags: hazard, weibull-distribution

My question is: how one derives a Weibull distribution for a lifetime of a system where parts are wearing out with time?

Provided that this is the lifetime analysis with aging is the main application of a Weibull distribution, I was surprised not to find a derivation why specifically this distribution and not any other describe the lifetime of an aging system.

Comment: Weibull can fit increasing, decreasing or constant hazard. "Wearing out" is an increasing hazard, so the Weibull can model that. It's not the only suitable model for such situations, it just happens to be common.

Comment: My guess would be that it is related to the [extreme value theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theory#Univariate_theory). This theory deals with distributions of $max[X_1,X_2,...,X_n]$, from which Weibul distribution arises at certain conditions. You could think of $X_i$ as a lifetime of components of a system, perhaps. So, the system fails when components fail.

Comment: @Glen_b: yes, with shape constants k<1, k=1 and k>1 respectively.
I've seen a Rayleigh distribution (k=2) pop out characterizing the efficiency of a system with a sufficiently large number of parts only a little number of which were locally critical for the efficiency. It seemed to derive from the Central Limit the assumption that the way in which they were critical were independent . Weibull seemed to generalize this result. In addition, since CLT is quite general I was expecting Weibull be derived from it (and to be the reason for Weibull aslo being in Fisher–Tippett–Gnedenko theorem).

Comment: @Aksakal: Would you have more details?

Comment: Andrei I don't think it's usually anything so formal; for most people the Weibull is a convenient ... well, *convention*, one that happens to often be a reasonable model. In some situations there may be a circumstance that leads us to expect the Weibull will approximately hold (I believe there are a number of characterizations of the Weibull), but for most people modelling survival times, those justifications are no more formally considered than when people assume normality to apply a t-test (they don't usually work out whether there are many small, not-too-dependent components being added).

Comment: @Aksakal And you were right - Weibull is just one of many distributions that have a behavior that approximates well the extreme value distributions of rare transitions between states (of minor damage accumulation) towards a state of complete disrepair. In the context of evolutionary populations genetics, this was described and formalized by John H. Gillespie Alan Orr.

Answer (score 2):

The reason the Weibull distribution is widely used in reliability and life data analysis is most likely due to its versatility. Depending on the parameters used, the Weibull distribution can be used to model a variety of failure laws.

For example, this source http://www.weibull.com/hotwire/issue14/relbasics14.htm  provides a good understanding of the versatility of the beta parameter, to quote:

"Effect of beta on Weibull failure rate

This is one of the most important aspects of the effect of β on the Weibull distribution. As is indicated by the plot, Weibull distributions with β < 1 have a failure rate that decreases with time, also known as infantile or early-life failures. Weibull distributions with β close to or equal to 1 have a fairly constant failure rate, indicative of useful life or random failures. Weibull distributions with β > 1 have a failure rate that increases with time, also known as wear-out failures. These comprise the three sections of the classic "bathtub curve." A mixed Weibull distribution with one subpopulation with β < 1, one subpopulation with β = 1 and one subpopulation with β > 1 would have a failure rate plot that was identical to the bathtub curve. An example of a bathtub curve is shown in the following chart."